# Javascript custom callback function not working

Tags: javascript

I'm play around with a certain callback function pattern, but encountered a road block. My plan is to have a generic function that calls another function to return a value. In this case, it's the current month.

```
function createDateObj(callback) {
    var dateObj = new Date(),
        date = dateObj.callback();
    return date;
}

var month = createDateObj(getMonth);

console.log(month);
```

The error received states getMonth is not defined. The dream is for the getMonth argument to replace "callback" to invoke the specified method and store it in a variable that will be returned.

It seems straight forward, but there it seems like the argument is not doing what I anticipate it to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function createDateObj(callback) {
    var dateObj = new Date(),
        date = dateObj[callback]();
    return date;
}

var month = createDateObj('getMonth');

console.log(month);
```

Comment: +1, but I'd change `callback` into something else, as this is not a callback.

Comment: It is a callback pattern from the book JavaScript Patterns, by Stoyan Stefanov - published by O'Reilly in 2010. The above works. I see it wasn't recognizing "." syntax because of the quotations, that I happened to miss. Ugh.